# $\forall f \in C[a,b], \; p_n \xrightarrow{u} f, \; p_n $ even polynomials, $\Leftrightarrow 0 \notin (a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that every continuous function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the uniform limit of a sequence of even polynomials if and only if $(a,b)$ does not contain the origin.

What I have tried, using ideas from other questions from this community:

$\Leftarrow)$ First we notice that $(a,b) \subseteq (0,b).$ We define $g:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $g(x)=f(h(x))=f(\sqrt x)$ which is

continuous in $[a,b]$. For this $g$ there is a sequence of polynomials $\{p_n\}$ such that $p_n \xrightarrow{u} g$. This implies that $$p_n(x^2)\xrightarrow{u} g(x^2)=f(x), \quad x \in [a,b].$$ Thus, there are even polynomials such that $p_n \xrightarrow{u} f$.

$\Rightarrow)$ I can't see this direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For simplicity assume that $[a,b]=[-1,1]$. And let $p_n$, a sequence of polynomials with even degree, converging to $f$ uniformly.

Now, for every $x$, $p_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ and $p_n(-x)\rightarrow f(-x)$. However, since $p_n$ are even functions we get $p_n(-x)=p_n(x)$. Therefore, we deduce that $p_n(x)$ and $p_n(-x)$ converge to the same limit hence $f(x)=f(-x)$. So, $f$ must be an even function.

To sum up if $f$ is not an even function then we cannot find such a sequence of polynomials, which proves the $\Rightarrow$ direction.

Comment: The hypothesis implies in your proof that $f$ is even. Or equivalently, if $f$ is not even, then the hypotheses are not true. But what we want to prove is that the hypothesis implies that $0 \not \in (a,b)$.

Comment: @miguel I am proving the contrapositive of your $\Rightarrow$ i.e., if $0\in(a,b)$ then that implies not every function defined there is the uniform limit of a sequence of polynomials of even degree which is equivalent as proving every function is a limit of a sequence of even degree polynomials then that implies $0 \notin (a,b)$. Generally, $p \Rightarrow q$ is equivalent to not $q \Rightarrow $ not $p$.

Comment: I understand but, it is necessary to see that there is at least one $f$ which is not the uniform limit of a sequence of even polynomials. For this it is assumed that $f$ is the uniform limit of a sequence of even polynomials and we get that $f$ is even. This proves that this $f$ is not the uniform limit of even polynomials?

Comment: @miguel Right, so for instance  if $f(x)=x$ then $f$ cannot possibly be the limit of a sequence of even degree polynomials since $f$ is not even. So if $0 \in (a,b)$ there are functions that are not the limit of even degree polynomials

Comment: I'm sorry, I still do not understand. You proved that $f$ is an even function, why $f$ can not be the uniform limit of a sequence of even polynomials?

Comment: @miguel I did not manage to respond before you accepted the answer. If you still need any clarification please dont hesitate to ask

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58022/discussion-between-miguel-and-clark).

Comment: So basically the proof can start supposing (or given f such that it's not even) that $f$ is not even and then we have to show that $f$ is not the uniform limit of a sequence of polynomial. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: @AnneliseToft Yes that is correct, and it is proven that $f$ is not the limit of a sequence of polynomials of even degrees because only an even function $g$ can.

Comment: I think a rigorous proof is needed for this problem. We just need to show the following: If $0 \in(a,b)$, then there exist a continuous function $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that it's not the uniform limit of a sequence of even polynomials. Proof (attempt): We propose a not even function $f$ and continuous in $[a,b]$.Now we must show that there exist an $ \epsilon >0$ and that for every $N \in \mathbb N : n \ge N$ and $\vert P_n(x) - f(x) \vert \ge \epsilon$. But I don't know how to continue the proof. Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: @AnneliseToft Hmm, I think it is easier to prove this using a contradiction, are you familiar with proofs by contradiction?

Comment: sure, so the statement will now be: $0 \in $(a,b) and every continuous function $f$ in [a,b] is the uniform limit of a sequence of even polynomial

Comment: @AnneliseToft Right, so we assume that this is true and we will try to reach a contradiction. If this is true then the function $f(x) =x$ must be the uniform limit of a sequence of even polynomials do you agree so far?

Comment: yes I agree, so we take a particular function $f(x)=x$ and this must be a uniform limit of a sequence of even polynomials

Comment: @AnneliseToft Exactly. Now we can find a $\delta >0$ such that $   (-\delta   ,\delta) \subset (a,b)$. Also $f(-\delta)=-\delta$ and $f(\delta)=\delta$ in particular $f(-\delta) \neq f(\delta)$.  Now we will use the uniform convergence hypothesis. Are you aware that uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence?

Comment: Yes I'm aware (it was proven days ago in my class)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59270/discussion-between-clark-and-annelise-toft).